# How do use a wildcard in a regex call?

Tags: regex, url

I am trying to use a regex call to search for url patterns. How should I write a regex call that will look for a specific domain up until a certain point?

For example:
A call that will look for anything with https://www.example.com/hello_world in the url and then anything else after '/hello_world' will still be `true`:

https://www.example.com/hello_world/chicago

or

https://www.example.com/hello_world/newyork

and so on and so forth.

I currently have:

`http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/hello_world`

and this works, but I can't figure out how to use the wildcard (*) for this solution.

Comment: why do you need to match more if it doesn't matter? What you have should suffice.

Comment: Interesting. I was just thinking that. It will return true even if the ending is different?

Comment: As long as your match is just a substring match, not an exact pattern match.  I don't know what you're using to do this, but normally you wouldn't care what's after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
^https:\/\/www\.example\.com\/hello_world(?=\/|$).*$
```

[**DEMO REGEX**](https://regex101.com/r/fS8rA4/3)

`(?=\/|$)` is positive lookahead `\/` or `$` (break line)

Comment: This is a great solution. I think the point that @ergonaut makes is the most useful for my purposes. I will definitely use your solution in the future

Comment: I guess a more "correct" regex will be `^https:\/\/www\.example\.com\/hello_world(?=(?:\/.*)?$)`.